# Repeat list object n times

Tags: r

This seems like an easy one (and it probably is), but since I'm braindead, I'm ready to get on the shame wall.

How to copy a list object `n` times, and wrap it up in a list afterwards? Something like this:

```
list(foo = "", bar = 0)
```

in order to get:

```
list(
    list(foo = "", bar = 0),
    list(foo = "", bar = 0)
    )
```

---

**NOTE:**
for loops are considered cheating

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Well, `rep` works (and is "vectorized") if you simply wrap the list in another list...

```
x <- list(foo = "", bar = 0)
rep(list(x), 2)
```

That trick can also be used to assign `NULL` to an element in a list:

```
x[2] <- list(NULL)
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a two-line script that does what you want:

```
el <- list(foo = "", bar = 0)
dups <- list(el)[rep(1,N)]
```

Note that this will work for ANY object "el", not just a list. It uses the trick of indexing a list like a vector, with single-bracket [ ] notation (and repeated indices).

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps `replicate`?  Something like:

```
L <- list(foo = "", bar = 0)
W <- replicate(10, L, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes a loop is the simplest:

```
x <- list(foo = "", bar = 0)
lx <- vector("list", 2)
for (i in 1:length(lx)) lx[[i]] <- x
```

If you need individual names you can allocate them at-once with `names(lx) <- ...`, or otherwise build the list from an empty one and index into it for each addition `lx[[i]]` - that is less efficient than pre-allocation.

A slightly trickier way is to lapply on a vector of length `n`:

```
 lapply(1:2, function(j) x)
```

Just put in a dummy `j` for each element and return your variable trivially (using questionable assumptions about scope).